# Test if a SQL Server column exists without using the schema?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

A 3rd party DB we read in ADO.Net recently added a column in a new version of their code. It's a fkey to a new table.

We have read-only access to the data tables, so *in theory* cannot rely on the schema to do this. So...

1) is INFORMATION_SCHEMA *always* available for items you can access, or is it possible we will not have rights even to tables we can read?

2) if (1) is "bad", what would be the canonical solution? In SQL itself I would do a `SELECT * FROM x WHERE 1=0` and then test the headers, is there an equivalent test in .Net?

Comment: Information schema seems like probably the best way to go.  Yes, it's possible you won't have access, depending on your user's permissions.

Comment: I'm very hesitant to use the schema in that case.

Comment: `is it possible we will not have rights even to tables we can read?` - [yes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25667/5203).

Comment: we are using SELECT TOP(0) * from (your select statement goes there) a. to validate all references. The main difference with your approach (1=0) is that in my version you can add ORDER BY to the inner query. You might not need that as we needed to validate the whole query that could be any form, not just single column

Comment: Good point Dmitrij, I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the column names (values are optional) from any Table or Query via a little XML.

**Example**

```
Declare @AnyTableOrQuery Table (EmpID int,EmpName varchar(50),Salary int,Location varchar(100))
Insert Into @AnyTableOrQuery Values 
 (1,'Arul',100,null)
,(2,'Jane',120,'New York')

Select B.*
 From ( values (cast((Select Top 1 * From @AnyTableOrQuery for XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL) as xml))) A(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Column_Name  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Column_Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  A.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./*') as C2(a)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Column_Name Column_Value
EmpID       1
EmpName     Arul
Salary      100
Location
```

> **EDIT**

@MauryMarkowitz Provided a much better solution (see comment below)

```
sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql =  N'Select * from YourTable'
```

Comment: Fascinating! I hate working with XML in SQLS, but this is a solution!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Happy to help.   I was a slow adopter of XML, but have "discovered" it to be useful in certain situations.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz If all-SQL solutions are fine, then I'd use [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz TREMENDOUSLY BETTER !!   Thanks for the tip

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I'll certainly add this arrow to my quiver.  It provides more information, but a couple of drawbacks... doubled the avg runtime 403ms vs 198ms and being a sp it does not integrate well in a TVF.     Either way, thanks again for the direction.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti `being a sp it does not integrate well in a TVF` - [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @GSerg That's it!  I'm doing a deep dive to see what else I've missed.  This morning, I was feeling pretty good about myself.  Now, not so much.  :)